# Multiple keypress actions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events

I have this animated character that changes every time when I press navigation keys.

This character can jump, but if i try with `spaceBar`+`rightKey`. Nothing happens as I expected.

Character jumps normally and don't take `right` jump.

**I want-**

I tried to add a box in window, so that this character shouldn't go across this box, they can only jump/walk over it.
I want to bind keys for making a directional jump.

**Code-**

```
if(spaceBar)
    {
        box.stop(true,false).animate({top:xPos-50},10, function(){
            box.animate({top:xPos},100);
        })
```

**I tried**

```
if(spaceBar,rightKey)
    {
        box.stop(true,false).animate({top:xPos-50},10, function(){
            box.animate({top:xPos},100);
        })
```

But that didn't do trick.

For more information-

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/n52bK/7/)

Comment: `if(spaceBar && rightKey)` for a logical `and`.

Comment: Maybe have a look at [gameQuery](http://gamequeryjs.com/). It makes game development easier (input, output, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@da_re was right in his comment, he should have posted an answer.

`if(spacebar && rightKey)`